# date format as yyyy/dd/mm and convert into dd/mm/yyyy in excel

Tags: excel, date-formatting

i have a column in excel where data is in mix format as some date are in dd/mm/yyyy and some date are in yyyy/dd/mm
i want to convert dates which are only in yyyy/dd/mm --> dd/mm/yyyy
[image]

what is the way i can do this?

i tried concatenate(left())  and concatenate(middle()) and concatenate(right()) and then concate() to combine all this 3 different fields but then it is messing up the true date format i want that is dd/mm/yyyy as some dates are already in dd/mm/yyyy and i made used concatenate() for format yyyy/dd/mm

Comment: What is the concatenate formula you used? Please can you share

Comment: for year =CONCATENATE(LEFT(B99,1)),for month=CONCATENATE(RIGHT(B99,2)) , for day =CONCATENATE(MID(B99,3,2))

Comment: Beware that when you write "yyyy" people assume 4-digit years; but your image shows dates with 2-digit years, which is a whole another problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the input data in text format in column **A**. In column **B** you have the output in the equivalent date format (not text format). This is the proper way to handle dates. You asked to convert it to another text format, but I think it is better to have them as an Excel date type.

The following formula does that:

```
=LET(rng, A1:A4, texts, DROP(REDUCE("", rng, LAMBDA(acc,text,
  VSTACK(acc, TEXTSPLIT(text,"/")))),1),
  first, INDEX(texts,,1), second, INDEX(texts,,2), third, INDEX(texts,,3),
  MAP(first, second, third, LAMBDA(a,b,c, IF(LEN(a)=4, DATE(a, c, b),
    DATE(c, b, a))))
)
```

The formula returns an array, so there is no need to drag down the formula, useful for a large input data set. If you prefer to drag the formula down, then you can use the following formula:

```
=LET(text, TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/"), first, INDEX(text,1,1), second, INDEX(text,1,2),
  third, INDEX(text,1,3), IF(LEN(first) = 4, DATE(first, third, second), 
    DATE(third, second, first))
)
```

**Note**: If you really want the dates in text format, then you can do it by replacing `DATE` function with: `a&"/"&c&"/"&b` and `c&"/"&b&"/"&a` respectively or to encapsulate `DATE` output with `TEXT` function, for example, `TEXT(DATE(a, c, b), "mm/dd/yyyy")` in the format of your preference.

Here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

The previous solution works because we have a way to identify the year as a 4-digit number. If the year has 2-digits, then you need to build a logic to differentiate a year from a month or a day.

Because the data is in Excel date format (internally it is stored as a whole number), then **you can format the date in the format of your preference without changing the data**. In the screenshot, you see the dates in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. Having the data as a date type, you can use all Excel functionalities for working with dates. Having dates in text data type will have more limitations.

Here is the output using the UK locale and returning the dates in `dd/mm/yyyy`, but it is the same output data, just different visualization:

[image: output in the UK locale]